# Fixed position DIV that works fine in Chrome and Safari but not in IE11

Tags: html, css, fixed

This CSS causes a Button to be anchored at the bottom of the screen of our website. The button stays anchored to the bottom of the page when scrolling up or down. In IE, it just renders the button right where the DIV code is located instead of floating it and anchoring it to the bottom of the browser. Chrome and Safari both show the button at the bottom right of the browser window. I have gone through several articles and tried different CSS settings but cannot seem to get it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<style type="text/css">
    div[id="bottomButton"] {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: -20px;
        right: 45px;
        border: none;
        z-index: 50;
        border-color: transparent;
        width: inherit;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: you can use #bottomButtom instead of [id="bottomButton"].

Comment: Do you have a doctype on the page?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eL4Vy/1/  Worked for me in IE9

Comment: Sounds like an html error somewhere. Validate your HTML, it'll tell you if you left a tag open: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 1):

you are missing HTML doctype in your code. Try below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #bottomButton {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: -20px;
        right: 45px;
        border: none;
        z-index: 50;
        border-color: transparent;
        width: inherit;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bottomButton">
<button>mybutton</button>
</div>

</body>


</html>
```